# Libgdx - Using Tween engine to change alpha on screen using shaders

Tags: libgdx, shader, tween

So I have a peculiar problem when trying to change the visibility of an actor using tween engine.  Below is my render method. It works if i remove the shader so i know its not a problem with my Tween class.  Has anyone encountered this before, or knows a work around?

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    shader.begin();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);
    stage.getBatch().setShader(shader);
    manager.update(delta);
    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}
```

Comment: What exactly your the problem?

Comment: never mind i've solved it.  The problem was making an actor fade, using tween engine. Which was working when i  used the default shader on the batch.  So I worked out the problem was in my shader, i needed to multiply texColor.a by v_color.a